# How can I copy data from an int4 vector into an int8 vector?

Tags: opencl

I'm trying to write a kernel where one of the parameters is an 8 element vector of type int4. I am then trying to read the vector into local memory and then copy the data from the vector into an int8 vector. Then I want to store the int8 vector into an output vector.

I've tried to use two int4 vectors for each half of the int8 vector, but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
__kernel void vecload(__global int4* vecA,
                      __global int* vecR) {

int id = get_local_id(0);

__local int4 vA;

vA = vecA[id];

int8 v = (int8)((int4)(vA.s0),(int4)(vA.s1);

vstore8(v, 0, vecR);
}
```

The output displays the first element of vecA four times and then fourth element four times as well. It's supposed to display all 8 elements of the vector.

Comment: `int4` is not a standard type in the C language, so what it means and how it is stored is up to the compiler you're using. Its documentation should describe it.

Comment: also, you have a non-c  ((and probably buggy) syntax in there.

Comment: I'm working in OpenCL with the C++ Wrapper

Comment: An int4 only has four elements, so it is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve. In any case, you are using vA.s0, this explicitly accesses the first element if vA. Try using int8 v = (int8)(vA, vA).

Answer (score 0):

`int4` and `int8` refer to OpenCL vector data types containing 4 or 8 integers respectively. In your code, the line

```c
int8 v = (int8)((int4)(vA.s0),(int4)(vA.s1));
```

(you forgot a closing bracket) contains the expression `(int4)(vA.s0)` which is equivalent to `(int4)(vA.s0, vA.s0, vA.s0, vA.s0)`, resulting in

```c
int8 v = (int8)(vA.s0, vA.s0, vA.s0, vA.s0, vA.s1, vA.s1, vA.s1, vA.s1);
```

What you want is something like this

```c
int8 v = (int8)(vA.s0, vA.s1, vA.s2, vA.s3, vA.s0, vA.s1, vA.s2, vA.s3);
```

or if you want two consecutive elements from `vecA` in `v` then use

```c
int4 vA = vecA[2*id  ];
int4 vB = vecA[2*id+1];
int8 v = (int8)(vA.s0, vA.s1, vA.s2, vA.s3, vB.s0, vB.s1, vB.s2, vB.s3);
```

Also there is no need to make `vA` `__local` since you are not sharing any data within a thread block.